# Somehow my activity can not extend MapActivity, why?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a simple android map application. the code runs fine as long as i am extending "Activity". The moment i change it to "MapActivity", do the necessary imports and run the emulator again. My app fails to start. I have searched a lot, but there seems to be no answer for this problem. Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Paste the logcat trace after the app crashes.

Comment: did you declare the <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library> in your manifest file?

Comment: Also, verify that your emulator is based on an SDK that includes the Google APIs, and not just the base SDK.  If you test on a device, you won't have to worry about this difference.

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked the following things?

- Are you using the Google APIs version of the SDK? If you aren't then the maps library wouldn't load.
- Go to your manifest file and put `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` if it isn't already there.

For the first one, you can select Google APIs ver. {4, 5, 7, 8} from the android tab in the property box for the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Check the fallowing point of your application.

1-:Permission in androidManifast file for useing map.

2-:Add the library in androidManifast file for using map.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

3-:Add unImplemented method.

```
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

4-:  check the fallowing import

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
```

if you do not get solution after the above then you should debug  your code and and show the log cat.

I hope after that you got your solution .

Comment: Thanks, did get the solution.. turns out that all you have to do is get the basics right.. i didnt add the library file appropriately in the exact way it needed to be

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing against Android 2.2 with Google APIs?

The MapActivity doesn't exist in the vanilla Android 2.2 - you need the Google APIs version.

```
   Right Click on your Project.Select properties and Android then check the google Api which you want to use in it
```

. check the Google APIs which you need

[image]

You'll also need this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1) add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` just before closing  tag in your Manifest.xml file

2) import the following:

```
 <br>import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
 <br>import com.google.android.maps.MapView;<br>
```

3) in eclipse manue bar, click on project >> properties >>Android(from sidebar)>> from "project target window" check "Google APIs">> Apply changes>> Ok

4) Open your Activity.java file, now add YourActivity extends MapActivity

5) point your curser on red underlined class name, it will show option for "add unimplimented methods", click on it

It solved my problem. hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

When developing new android application project change the "Compile with" option to the "Google APIs 8" or any one you installed and your emulator "Target" must also be "googleAPIs 8".
I hope your problem get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

also set target of your project:

1. click the right on the project
2. go to preferences>android>set target as which u want but should be google api inc...
3. then the same target put into your mainfest file...
4. create new emulater of the same target having google api inc...
5. test it...

your activity should work

Answer (score 0):

Following solved my problem.

Go to project->properties->android

Tick mark GoogleAPIs(API Level->8)